# Material icons missing from Font Image

Tags: codenameone

I'm referring the icons from following link. Some of the icons nice to have as part of Font Image class. Example: Label is part of the library and Label_Important isn't. Is there any plans to add the missing icons to make it up to date? Please advise

https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem see [this](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2421). Google stopped maintaining the icon font and there is no newer version. We'll probably migrate to a new icon font and include a wider selection as a result but that will require some work. Notice you can install your own [icon fonts](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-icon-fonts-such-as-fontello.html).